# Update layer with user input in Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, user-interface

My goal is to request a threshold value from user and then use it to recompute a binary mask for NDVI raster. But when I change a value in the ui.Textbox `ndvi_textbox` it throws an error: `Invalid argument specified for ee.Number(): 0.2`

[Here's my code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/7145e113589e61f50603675592df9525):

```
var ndvi = ee.ImageCollection("LANDSAT/LC8_L1T_32DAY_NDVI")
  .first();

var threshold = 0.1;

function set_threshold(thrsh) {
  var thresholded = ndvi.gt(ee.Number(thrsh));
  Map.addLayer(thresholded);
}


var ndvi_textbox = ui.Textbox({
  value: threshold,
  onChange: set_threshold,
  style: {position: 'top-center'}
});

ui.root.setLayout(ui.Panel.Layout.absolute());
ui.root.add(ndvi_textbox);

set_threshold(threshold);

Map.setCenter(6.969, 47.448, 9);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

EE is very picky with its types. `threshold` starts out as a number, but input field generates strings. If you convert it to a number before wrapping it into an `ee.Number`, you should be fine.

```
var thresholded = ndvi.gt(ee.Number(Number(thrsh)));
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/9d452a28950eecd1f1916321c8bdd421